# Is there a way to test an in-development NPM package via NPX?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npx

I'm working on an NPM package that is intended for use solely via `npx *`, a la packages like `create-nuxt-app`.

Is there a way to test my package with `npx *`? In other words, run my bin script without installing the package.

I've read [this discussion](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7137), which suggests perhaps there isn't. I realise I can test the *installation*, rather than mere *running*, of my a packge via something like [Yalc](https://github.com/wclr/yalc), but Yalc provides only `yalc add *`, which simulates `npm install *`, not `npx *`.

What's the best approach here?

Comment: 16 seconds after I posted it. That's got to be some sort of SO record.

Comment: i actually didn't read your question properly. no idea about testing via `npx`, though you can still use `npm link` to use it directly

Comment: Yeah I've read that blog post, and the use case is indeed for installing/importing a package rather than merely run up. *Surely* I can't be the first person to come up against this. How would they have tested the likes of `create-nuxt-app` and `create-react-app`?

Comment: afaik, `npx` does the same thing as `npm install` and `npm run`. so you can test the js file directly ig. when I created a simple `npx` script, i tested the app manually and then deployed it

Comment: But `npm run *` is for running scripts defined in the `scripts` array, not the `bin` map, no? Or are you saying define the bin script under `scripts` for testing purposes?

Comment: And yes `npx` basically does what `npm install` does, but it doesn't affect the project e.g. add a `node_modules` directory or add dependencies to its `package.json`.

Comment: yeah, by `npm run` I meant running the bin script. When I was testing, I created a dev script in package.json which would mimic my use case. Maybe you can try `npm link` as a global module? Then I think you can call it directly.  `npx` creates node_modules in the global cache directory

Comment: Thanks, I'll explore that. Are you saying that scripts executed from `scripts` and `bin` are run in the same way/context/privileges, so I can test whatever I want to be the bin script as a run script instead? If I've understood you right...

Comment: I don't have that much idea about this. My use case was very simple. I was using `inquirer` to ask some questions and create corresponding dot files. I think mostly it should be the same.

Comment: Appreciate the help - I'll dig further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean why don’t you just publish yow code to npm. Change the version of it

```
{
“name”:”yowPackage”,
“version”:”0.0.1-dev”,
…
}
```

then you can test yow package

```
$ npx yowPackage@0.0.1-dev arguments
```

Then once yow code works publish the oficial version

```
{
“name”:”yowPackage”,
“version”:”1.0.0”,
…
}
```

```
$ npx yowPackage@1.0.0 arguments
```

Check this to learn more about it

https://docs.npmjs.com/adding-dist-tags-to-packages

Comment: Ah I didn't actually know npm supported dist tags - thanks for flagging that up.

Answer (score 1):

After much digging and discussion it seems `npm init *` is identical to `npx *` **provided the package name begins with `create-`.** ([Source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-init)).

So:

```
npx create-nuxt-app
```

is actually the same as

```
npm init nuxt-app
```

If your package doesn't begin with `create-` this won't work.

You can use either approach to pass args, if the package allows it.

This means you can use traditional NPM package testing mechanisms e.g. `npm-link` or something like Yalc, but test via `npm *` syntax rather than `npx *`.